# Pyinstaller and Taipy

Tags: python, pyinstaller, taipy

Have anyone successfully made executable file using taipy module and pyinstaller.
I made a new virtual environment, and pip install numpy, and pandas first. Then I pip install taipy.
My program is as simple as :

import taipy

print('Hello Taipy')

I have compiled the program using pyinstaller

pyinstaller -F testtaipy.py

The exe file is created but when I run the program, it returned error message.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The "question" only describes what you did and that's it. What is the problem you are trying to solve? Do you get an error running pyinstaller? Do you get an error running the executable?

Comment: `python -m pip install taipy`.  The docs are here: https://pypi.org/project/taipy

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi,  I already compiled the python file, but when I run the executable it will show error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testcompile.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  ....
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\iront\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI88202\\taipy\\config\\version.json'
[24360] Failed to execute script 'testcompile' due to unhandled exception!

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough: Please [edit] your question to clarify instead of cramming errors into comments.